# How to use a GoDaddy TLS certificate for my Mongo Replica Set internal node authentication?

Tags: cert-manager, mongodb, tls

We have a wildcard domain `*.apps.acme.net` in GoDaddy. This way, when we use our mongo database, we only need to use this:

```
mongosh --tls --h rs1.apps.acme.net
```

The mongod.conf is as follow:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/mongodb/ssl/mongodb.pem
    clusterFile: /etc/mongodb/ssl/mongodb.pem

security:
  clusterAuthMode: x509
  authorization: enabled

#replication configuration
replication:
  replSetName: docker-replica-set
```

Basically, I would like to authenticate the nodes using that certificate but for some reason, it's asking for the CA file even though it's a public certificate authority (GoDaddy).

So, the question is.. why when I try to add internal node authentication, this setup fails? If I remove the security section, everything works fine and the traffic is being encrypted as expected. But when I enabled `security.authorization`, it started to fail  asking for a keyFile because we're running a replica set. I'd like to use a x509 certificate instead of a `keyfile` since it's the one recommended by Mongo.

I was also looking at the following commands, but never figured out how they worked tbh:

`certificateSelector`

`clusterCertificateSelector`

I tried something like this, but nothing:

```
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateSelector: 'subject=CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2'
```

Any help or tips would be amazing. Thank you in advance.